# How to structure this variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now the form can send me three values for my boolean fields.

```
false
true
""

procedure.needsAuditing = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["needsAuditing"]);
```

How to I structure this variable so that if it is `""` it will not try to convert it to a Boolean but instead pass `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a third state for a `bool` which indicates *not determined*(`null`) you can use a [`Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

So change the property to:

```
public bool? needsAuditing{ get; set; }
```

and assign it in this way:

```
object needsAuditing = collection["needsAuditing"];
if(needsAuditing == null)
    procedure.needsAuditing = (bool?) null;
else
    procedure.needsAuditing = Convert.ToBoolean(needsAuditing);
```

Side-note: you should consider to use pascal case propertynames. See [Property Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Any way to consolidate this some?  My model is set up like this.  `public <Nullable>bool needsAuditing {get; set; }`.  I have about 5 of these fields and would hate to add 20+ lines of code.

Comment: @JamesWilson: So what type is `collection` and what returns it's indexer? Is it really object and why, can't you use a strongly typed collection?

Comment: collect is a FormCollection.

Comment: I tried to use FormCollection collection because my strongly typed model was not picking up my dropdown boxes for some reason.  So I was trying to force fill them through FormCollection.

Comment: Actually I may have fixed my own mistake.  I originally had my values as "0", "1", "".  Thinking that is how the model wanted them because that is how SQL stored them.  Then I changed the valus to "true", "false" and "".  And it seems my strongly typed model is now picking everything up.

Comment: Yep just verified.  Working as it should now.  Strongly typed models to the rescue after silly developer mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this...first make `procedure.needsAuditing Nullable` see this[Link For More Details For Nullable Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).
then do it like this...

```
bool? c;
    procedure.needsAuditing =collection["needsAuditing"]==""? c=null: Convert.ToBoolean(collection["needsAuditing"]);
```

Comment: This was the one I was looking for, thank you.  I like it all on one line if possible.

Comment: Does this work? I get "there is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'bool'"

Comment: procedure.needsAuditing must be a nullable type: "bool?".

Comment: @JamesWilson i update my answer...you to define your procedure.needsAuditing  nullable to accept it null .see here why..in more details...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx .
So after defining it nullable you can use i mentined above

Comment: @ColmPrunty i update my answer...you to define your procedure.needsAuditing  nullable to accept it null .see here why..in more details...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx .
So after defining it nullable you can use i mentined above

Comment: Thanks for the update, the property was nullable.  But I have not  tested your new option as I no longer use the FormCollection.  Made a couple changes to my view which allowed me to use the strongly typed model to get it to work.  Thank you again for the answer. :)

Comment: @JamesWilson you can try code it will work,,i tried and tested...,hope if u need something like this in future than it will help u a bit

Answer (score 3):

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["needsAuditing"].ToString())
    procedure.needsAuditing = null;
else 
    procedure.needsAuditing = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["needsAuditing"]);
```

Assuming `needsAuditing` is a `bool?`

Edit: I did an `if else` instead of a `?` because the compiler would complain that there's no conversion between `null` and `bool` (which would be the return type of `Convert.ToBoolean`)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ModelBinder` which will convert your string input to nullable `bool` type.

Your method after that will look like this:

```
void Method(bool? value)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `procedure.needsAuditing` property to the result of the following method:

```
    bool? ParseInput(string input)
    {
        int integerInput;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out integerInput))
            return integerInput == 1;
        return null;
    }
```